# Freeze TCP implementation in Windows

Tags: windows, tcp

I need to customize the normal TCP implementation so that I can implement and test Freeze TCP as described in the following paper:

> T. Goff, J. Moronski, D. S. Phatak, and V. Gupta, Freeze-TCP: a True End-to-end TCP Enhancement Mechanism for Mobile Environments, In Proceedings of IEEE INFOCOM 2000'

Can anybody suggest the best way to go about this considering that my OS in Windows?

Editing since I think I didn't explain properly:

> The basic idea behind freeze TCP is to freeze the sender stream before disruption occurs. The receiver sends a "zero window advertisement" to the sender. The sender stops sending packets upon the receipt of this option. When receiver can connect again, it sends it's actual window size so that the sender can avoid slow-start.

I checked out windows socket option SO_RCVBUF which dictates the receive window size. I was just wondering if playing around with this would be useful?

Comment: Either give Microsoft an exorbitant fee to get  access to their networking stack or don't use windows.

Comment: run a virtual machine with linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the interested, it seems like the only way to do this is if you have access to the source code :-(